# using findOne inside a foreach()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, async-await

I am just learning Mongoose and NodeJS. Attempting my own project after finishing a tutorial.

I have two Models: "Flat" (containing flat numbers) and "User" (users owning the Flats).

```
var flatsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    flat: String,
    users:[{
        userId: String,
        username: String,
        userType: String //owner or tenant
    }]
});

var Flat = new mongoose.model("Flat", flatsSchema);

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    flatsRegistered: [{
        flat: String,
        userType: String //owner or tenant
    }]
});

var User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

A User may own multiple Flats, and in each Flat, there can be multiple users.

In the "Flat" model, I have the users living in each flat in the "users" property. I also have flats owned by the users in the flatsRegistered property of "User" model.

Now when a user logs in to his webpage - I want to pass all the details of the flats he is registered to - with all the other users in those flats.

I tried the

```
flatsRegistered.foreach((userFlat) => {
    Flat.findOne({ flat: userFlat }, function (err, flatFound) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(flatFound.users) //assign flatFound.users to a variable which i pass to webpage using ejs
        }
    });
}
```

Trouble is the foreach loop completes before the Flat.findOne can complete. Is there any way to force Flat.findOne to complete before foreach can continue? After reading up things, I am discovering concepts of async/await and promise - but I really don't know how to use those (and even if they are applicable). Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `for of` with `await` like this:

```js
for (const userFlat of flatsRegistered) {
  const flatFound = await Flat.findOne({ flat: userFlat });
  console.log(flatFound.users) //assign flatFound.users to a variable which i pass to webpage using ejs
}
```